# Ubuntu display messed up

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, display, display-resolution

My monitor is a Sony Bravia TV. Before, when I had onboard intel graphics, I used to use a VGA, with a resolution of 1920×1080. After adding a Nvidia card (no drivers), I changed to the HDMI option, and I booted to see my resolution stuck on 800×600, everything is HUGE, and compressed. Built in display in the settings is unavailable, it is simply greyed out. Would installing the Nvidia drivers change this?

Comment: Possibly, but it depends on what specific Nvidia card it is. Only very new ones may need the Nvidia drivers. The easiest way to install the proprietary Nvidia drivers is in "Software and updates" (settings), and then the "Additional drivers" tab.

Comment: Of course, it is the zotac GTX 1050, pretty new...Sorry I didn't mention the card earlier.

Comment: It also depends on the Ubuntu version you're using. 16.04 should work, if you have the latest [HWE kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack). If you don't, you'll need to either install that as described in the link, or install the drivers from "Additional drivers".

Comment: Sorry, running Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the newest Nvidia driver from software and updates fixed the resolution on re-boot up.
Thank you to whoever tried to help me.